# Update React Native app to App Store that is published through expo

Tags: ios, react-native, app-store, expo

I have published an app to App Store through Expo and it handled all the ios certificates things for me at that time. But, Now I have re-created the whole app without expo and i have fetched the certificates from expo servers ie `expo fetch:ios:certs` Now I am not sure how can i use those certificates for my new build in bare React Native. I have managed to get it working on Play Store.